# Customize chisq.test() arguments for groups

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

Inspired by this question, [Get `chisq.test()$p.value` for several groups using `dplyr::group_by()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991993/get-chisq-testp-value-for-several-groups-using-dplyrgroup-by) 
I am doing Chi-squared tests over a few groups but I need to customize the default chisq.test arguments but I got an error. Please see how I could improve my code. Thank you

```
data%>%
  group_by(col4,col5)%>%
  do(broom::tidy(chisq.test(x=(.$col1, .$col2),simulate.p.value = T)))
```

It seems to me that multiple arguments are not allowed. The error I got was

```
 Error: unexpected ',' in:
"  group_by(col4,col5)%>%
  do(broom::tidy(chisq.test(x=(.$col1,"
```

The default works fine.

```
data%>%
      group_by(col4,col5)%>%
 do(broom::tidy(chisq.test(.$col1, .$col2)))
```

Comment: `(.$col1, .$col2)` is not valid code. You can see this is exactly where the code breaks in the error message - where you try to add a comma and specify `.$col2`. Did you mean `c(.$col1, .$col2)` ? or `cbind(.$col1, .$col2)` ?

Comment: Don't feel bad, we all make typos and miss little things from time to time. Just make sure you are getting the result you expect compared to the version of your code that is working. You could also use `do(broom::tidy(chisq.test(x=.$col1, y=.$col2)))` I think.